# Best way to wait for an async value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap

The user requests a particular information from an external system.
Therefore a http request is sent to our system and wait for a response.

Normally it would be easy, but the external system is using SOAP.
So we send a request, and get asynchron an answer on a different controller.
In SOAP the Standard is to send a unique correlation ID, which we get back in an answer. We write the answer in a Database and check in the request thread if we already received an answer.

This can take 1s to 2 minutes.

```rb
TIMEOUT = 180

def async_answer(request)
  soap_request(request)

  tries = 0
  answer = nil
  until answer.present? || tries == TIMEOUT
    Income.connection.clear_query_cache
    answer = Income.find_by(ident: request.correlation)&.content
    (tries += 1) && sleep(0.5) if answer.blank?
  end
  
  Nokogiri::XML(answer)
end
```

The problem is, that when there are many requets, and the api has a long response times, that many processes blocking the system, because all are currently stucking in the until-loop.

An Idea is to use sidekiq for the waiting part, but then I cannot return the content in a http response which requestest the content.

Is this the best solution, or does someone have a better idea or a best practice to solve this?

Comment: You could replicate the upstream behavior: have the first endpoint return the database identifier and let the client request a second endpoint for the result. This involves polling on the client side but it doesn't block your server.

Comment: @Stefan as an alternative to polling you could use websockets (ActionCable) instead to notify the client.

Comment: Also you want to avoid phrases like "Whats the best way?" on stackoverflow as that will lead to the question being closed as opinion based. There are many options here and the correct answer will depend on the external collaborator (does it for example have webhooks that you can use instead of waiting?), your skill level and how much resources (time) you can commit to solving the issue.